# ActiveRecord: Name already in use within the application, where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to generate a scaffold but generating it I receive the following error:

```
rails generate scaffold foo
      invoke  active_record
The name 'Foo' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

Is there a command to find out exactly where this name is being used within my application?

Comment: I am actually aware of where the naming issue is coming from. What I am looking for is a command to indicate to me where the name is being used. I can see my self running into the issue on a larger application and rake command or something would be very useful when the situation arrises

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to find the file or source of any object/class/module. Also rails has open class concept so the class can be defined or refined in many files so we can not track the same.

but you can check if the name is exist for any object by following

```
Module.constants.include? "Foo"
```

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question but definitely a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using rubymine, there are a few ways you can do this. There is a "find usages" command that will find all location where a method, variable, etc. are used. There is a "jump to declaration" which in your case would be useful. It will jump to the spot where something is defined. (a class, module, variable, method). there is also a powerful search feature. In this case, search in path would allow you to search the entire application (including external gems being used). You can force case sensitivity on your search to only yield class / module names etc.

Answer (score 0):

Szuper tricky! For me the model name was stuck in memory in the Spring cache system.  Had to kill the `spring` process to free it up.

Look for this when you attempt the command:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 57104
Expected string default value for '--serializer'; got true (boolean)
  invoke  active_record
The name 'Admin' is either already used in your application or reserved 
by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator 
again.
```

If you see that Spring comment, try looking for spring in your processes and killing:

`ps -ef | grep spring`

find the id:

`501 54701 30654   0  1:43PM ??         0:04.83 spring app    | server | started 8 mins ago | development mode`

`501 30654     1   0 Tue03PM ttys000    0:03.82 spring server | server | started 142 hours ago`

and kill

`kill 30654`

Answer (score -1):

Thats just one of the given possibilities! Foo is a reserved Word. Ruby also reserves words that arent used as a Model/Module name already. For example you also cant create a model called `Configuration` eaven there is no class thats clled Configuration.

Comment: is Foo reserved word in rails? As per rails doc following are reserved and foo is not mentioned here http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/reservedwords

Comment: This is neither an official nor an complete list. If its not a Model created by the user then it needs to be an reserved word.

Comment: The question is not concerning the name `Foo`, it was general generic example meant to abstract the problem and enable to question to be relavant to a wider audience.